# Id null after JPA transaction commit Eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

USER MAPPING

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sec_t_usuario", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "sec_t_usuario", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idUsuario", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<Session> sessions;
```

SESSION MAPPING

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH  })
@JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private User user;
```

CODE LINKING TWO ENTITIES

```
 @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor=PlayTheGuruException.class)
 private Session createSession(final User user) throws PlayTheGuruException
 {
    final Session session = new Session();

    session.setActive(true);
    session.setLastLogin(Calendar.getInstance());
    session.setUser(user);

    user.addSession(session);

    entityManager.merge(user);

    return session;
}
```

MAIN METHOD

```
public Message<ResultDTO> registerUser(final Message<NewUserDataDTO> messageIn) throws PlayTheGuruException
{
    .
    .
    .
    final Session session = createSession(messageIn);
    .
    //here the user Id is still null
    .
```

Having this context, why when I return from createSession transactional method the user id is still null knowing that the transaction has been commited?

I have the queries log from eclipse links and show me that user is inserted and the id is assigned too but seems has not been refreshed in the code.

I have tried flush and get object user from session or directly and not works.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the content of `repository.saveUser()` method, please? It might occur that the `user` instance is detached.

Comment: it´s a simple 'merge' using entity manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `entityManager.merge()` (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge%28T%29)) method returns a managed instance. It seems to me that the `user` instance sent as parameter is not being attached. In other words, it's not what you'd call an "out" parameter, so you won;t have the ID set in that object. You need to use the returned object in order to find the generated ID.

The `session` instance is definitely not managed. And also its referenced `User` is not a managed instance.

Comment: OK. I will try your approach and tell you news. Thanks!

Comment: It works perfectly. I will not forget this concept anymore XD Thanks!